# Internet explore not getting cross domain django web service session cookie correctly 

Tags: django, internet-explorer, jsonp

My site (site A) is based on django，and i wrote a jsonp service on site A. I have another site (site B) that call the service.

I am experiencing a problem when i call the jsonp service on site B I found that the request.user.is_authenticated is false on the site A, even though I have logged into site A.

This doesn't appear to be a problem in firefox, which shows request.user.is_authenticated as true.

I suspect that this is a bug in internet explore bug regarding getting cross domain session cookies. Does any one have similar problem or how did you work around it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused. If you are logged into Site A, it doesn't necessarily mean you're also logged into site B. Or did you implement it such that you store a special cookie in browser that acts as a login token?

Anyway, I feel this is poor design in general. You shouldn't have 2 controllers in a system. If you really insist to keep a site B, you could solve this by using site A as an intermediary mechanism to communicate with site B. That way, you won't have to deal with browser incompatibilities at all.

If you want a central login system, use facebook connect or an equivalent social media tool.

Comment: sorry, i have a mistake in description. the question have edited again